# Is it possible to receive data from the server after few seconds while the server is streaming continuously?

Tags: python, sockets, tcpclient

If my server is sending TCP data from data1,.., data10 taking 1s for each data (total of 10s). And my client is receiving data with a gap of 2s. I want it to receive only data2, data4, data6, data8, data10. Is that possible to implement using socket programming in python?

Could someone give an idea/show how to write that in python?

Comment: A TCP stream guarantees that data will be received in order, if it is received at all.  To receive every other data item as you describe, the client would have to receive *everything*, and explicitly discard half of it.  Perhaps the client should specify, when it establishes connection with the server, what frequency of data updates it wants?  There's no point in the server sending data that isn't going to be used.

Comment: @jasonharper how could I specify when I establish the connection to the server about the frequency of the data?

Comment: Any way you want.  The client could send the desired update rate as the first (or only?) thing it sends to the server.  Or perhaps the server could be listening on multiple port numbers, each of which corresponds to a particular update rate.